# Selenium test go too fast and redirect to next page before clicking on element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, gherkin

Selenium test go too fast and redirect to next page before  clicking on element

I have the following test : login with multiple users loaded from excel file and create multiple persons  which is also loaded from excel file

the problem I meet is that the test goes to **create-person** page before the **login** done but when  setting Thread.sleep(1000) the test passed

for more clarification here is my code below

```
@Given("user logged in and populates the form and click create and logout")
public void user_logged_in_and_populates_the_form_and_click_create_and_logout() throws InterruptedException {
    userLoginCreationPage.init();
    logger.info("**************************************** init the driver && go to login page http://localhost:4200/login");

    for (UserLoginPageData userLoginPageData : userLoginPageDataList) {
        logger.info("Line  " + userLoginPageData.getRowIndex() + "from Excel file");
        userLoginCreationPage.enterUsername(userLoginPageData.getUsername());
        userLoginCreationPage.enterPassword(userLoginPageData.getPassword());
        userLoginCreationPage.clickOnLogin();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        logger.info(userLoginPageData.toString() + "is login");
        personCreationPage.init();
        logger.info("**************************************** init the driver && go to creation page http://localhost:4200/dossier-person/new");
        for (PersonPageData personPageData : personPageDataList) {
            if (userLoginPageData.getIdUser().equals(personPageData.getIdUser())) {
                personCreationPage.refresh();
                personCreationPage.enterUsername(personPageData.getUsername());
                personCreationPage.enterEmail(personPageData.getEmail());
                personCreationPage.enterPassword(personPageData.getPassword());
                personCreationPage.clickTab();
                personCreationPage.clickOnCreate();
                logger.info(personPageData.toString() + " ****************************************  is created by " + userLoginPageData.getUsername());
            }
        }
        userLoginCreationPage.clickOnLogout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [WebDriverWait](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html)

Comment: I use It for the first page loginpage and for the second page creatpersonspage and its not work